# Complex numbers confusion

Tags: complex-numbers

I am a little bit confused trying to understand complex numbers. I read Richard Feynman lectures on physics and in chapter about complex numbers he says:

10^is = x + iy | i - imaginary, s - real number

First of all how is it possible that real number multiplied by itself (i*s times) gives complex number (x+iy) ? Why it is complex number, how we know that ?

Second, why we choose exponential function e^i0, to represent complex numbers ? Why e not 10 or any other number ?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Complex numbers are sums of imaginary and real numbers. All real numbers are complex numbers by default, reals are a subset of complex numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the meaning of power?

$3^n$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ means $3 \times 3 \times \dots \times 3 $ for $n$ times.
However when we expand the meaning of power to rational power
$$ a ^ \frac{m}{n}=\sqrt[n]{a^m}$$
The previous concept does not work. The meaning of power is redefined. But in special case where the power is an natural number, the result is the same as before.

The negative power is defined too. It does not give you any sense about how many times multiplication we well have.

Then definition of power is extended to real numbers. Here, root square cannot help you. You need a more powerful definition for power

$$a^r=\exp(r \times \log a)$$

This re-definition is fantastic for real numbers and it does not contradict the previous definitions.

For complex numbers, we follow the same principle. We do nothing except for expansion of $\exp$ and $\log$ for complex numbers. $\exp$ and $\log$ for complex numbers are equal to the value of their Tylor expantion when you put a complex number in them. So, previous definitions of power are still preserved for real number.

Hence, the concept of multiplying $n$ times is just good for natural numbers.

> Why do we choose exponential for showing complex numbers?

Not always. One problem with complex numbers is that each complex number contains information two times as much as a real number. It can be shown in both ways

$$z=x+i y$$

$$z=r \exp(i \theta)= r \angle \theta$$

A complex number is a dot in 2D while a real number is a dot in 1D.

So you can show a dot with its $x$ and $y$. Alternatively, you can show it with magnitude ($r$) and angle($\theta$). Working with magnitude and angle gives you better view about how big a number is. In electrical engineering, a complex number can show an AC voltage. The magnitude shows the voltage while the angle shows the phase of sinusoidal waveform compared to an origin which is not such important in many cases. But why exponential? Just because of the following formula:

$$\exp(i \theta)=\cos(\theta)+i \sin(\theta)$$

$\exp(i \theta)$ is a unit vector ($sin^2+cos^2=1$). However it shows a direction. Combined with a magnitude ($r \exp(i \theta)$), it can show any complex number (or any 2D vector).

**Update**

$$\exp(i \theta)=1+(i\theta)+\frac{(i\theta)^2}{2!}+\frac{(i\theta)^3}{3!}+\frac{(i\theta)^4}{4!}+\frac{(i\theta)^5}{5!}+\frac{(i\theta)^6}{6!}+\dots=1+i\theta+\frac{-1 \theta^2}{2!}+\frac{-i \theta^3}{3!}+\frac{+ \theta^4}{2!}+\frac{i \theta^5}{5!}+\frac{-1 \theta^6}{6!}+\dots=(1+\frac{-1 \theta^2}{2!}+\frac{+ \theta^4}{2!}+\frac{-1 \theta^6}{6!}+\dots)+i(+\theta+\frac{-1 \theta^3}{3!}+\frac{ \theta^5}{5!}+\dots)=\cos(\theta)+i \sin(\theta)$$

Comment: Thanks. The formula: exp(iθ)=cos(θ)+isin(θ) was discovered by power series (Taylor series) or something else, what is the genesis of it ?

Comment: write the power series of exp and replace x with $i \theta$ and replace $i^2$ with $-1$. You see that it is equal to two parts. terms with odd and even powers of $\theta$. If you separate them, power series of sin and cos appears. The proof is very simple.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you were interested in developing a useful for an expression like $10^{is}$. First, you would want to make is consistent with the rules of exponents, like $10^{is}=e^{is\ln(10)}$, and you would probably also want to make it follow the rules of calculus like $$\frac{d}{ds}10^{i s}=i\ln(10)10^{is}.$$ This means that if you tried to derive the Taylor series for $10^{is}$, you would get $$10^{is}=1+is\ln(10)+\frac{(is\ln(10)^2}{2!}+\frac{(is\ln(10))^3}{3!}+\frac{(is\ln(10))^4}{4!}.$$ Since Taylor series converge absolutely, you could rearrange this sum as: $$\left(1-\frac{(s\ln(10))^2}{2}+\frac{(s\ln(10))^4}{4!}+...\right)+i\left(s\ln(10)-\frac{(s\ln(10))^3}{3!}+\frac{(s\ln(10))^5}{5!}+...\right).$$ Notice that the terms inside the brackets are all real. At this point, you might recognize the two series inside the brackets as $\cos(s\ln(10))$ and $\sin(s\ln(10))$ respectively. Thus, $$10^{is}=\cos(s\ln(10))+i\sin(s\ln(10)).$$ Thus, $10^{is}$ being a complex number is the only way to make it consistent with the math on the real numbers which we have already put in place.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, $10^{is} = x+ iy$, we can do this because this lets us find suitable values of $x$ and $y$, and if "a real number multiplies by itself $i$ times" is not a complex number, then we will find $y$ to be $0$, giving you a real number.

So, basically, letting $\text{something} = x+ iy$ does not mean that we are saying that $\text{something}$ should be a complex number, rather it **can** be one. This is because the real numbers form a subset of the complex numbers.